# My bootstrap modal is open by default / broken

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am an inexperienced developer who is having some issues with a bootstrap modal that should slide down the full width of the page when clicking on the 'Info' button. It was working fine until a few days ago but i'm not sure what has caused this issue. I am in the process of learning git so in future I can revert back to previous versions.

Here is the site: [deannoble.com.au](https://deannoble.com.au)

**This is the button that should open up the modal:**

```
    <span onclick="openNav()">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" href="../website/index.html" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-xl">Info</a>
      </button>
    </span>
```

**This is the content within the modal:**

```
    <div class="container over" href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">
      <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <h2 class="overlay-text">Hello  </h2>
              <h2 class="overlay-text">I'm a Melbourne-based UX/UI designer and also a pretty decent amateur baker.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**And this is the CSS**

````
.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(205, 178, 255, 0.95);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 1.2s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #4e3380;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: black;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 2rem;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 2rem;
  }
}

h2.overlay-text {
  color: #4e3380;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}```
````

Any help would be great.

Comment: Note that it's invalid HTML to have an `<a>` within a `<button>`

Comment: I enter in the website click on info and modal appears, which is the problem?

Comment: Thanks @sean good to know.

Comment: Hey @SimoneRossaini are you looking at it on desktop or on a mobile? It seems to work as it should on mobile but not on desktop.

Comment: On desktop ( Chrome)

Comment: That's really bizarre @SimoneRossaini . I'm on a mac using Chrome (tried Safari too) and I can see the modal text without clicking the 'info' button. When I do try clicking 'info' it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Try to clear all cache

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the HTML is invalid and the problem is no longer reproducable (clearing the cache "solved" the issue).

Comment: you mean 'is valid', all solve close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your cache, just delete it and all work.